# Django: Signal/Method called after "AppConfig.ready()"

Tags: django, django-signals, django-apps

I have an `AppConfig.ready()` implementation which depends on the readiness of an other application.

Is there a signal or method (which I could implement) which gets called after all application `ready()` methods have been called?

I know that django processes the signals in the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

But I don't want to enforce a particular ordering of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
   'app_a',
   'app_b',
   ...
]
```

How can "app_a" receive a signal (or method call) after "app_b" processed `AppConfig.ready()`?

(reordering `INSTALLED_APPS` is not a solution)

Comment: Django processes apps [in the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#initialization-process), so you should be able to put your code in the `ready()` method as long as you order your apps appropriately.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you for your hint. I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is No. Populating the application registry happens in `django.setup()`. If you look at the source code, you will see that neither [`apps.registry.Apps.populate()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/apps/registry.py#L122) nor [`django.setup()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/__init__.py) dispatch any signals upon completion.

Here are some ideas:

- You could dispatch a custom signal yourself, but that would require that you do that in all entry points of your Django project, e.g. `manage.py`, `wsgi.py` and any scripts that use `django.setup()`.
- You could connect to `request_started` and disconnect when your handler is called.
- If you are initializing some kind of property, you could defer that initialization until the first access.

If any of these approaches work for you obviously depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

So there is a VERY hackish way to accomplish what you might want...

Inside the `django.apps.registry` is the singleton `apps` which is used by Django to populate the applications. See `setup` in `django.__init__.py`.

The way that `apps.populate` works is it uses a non-reentrant (thread-based) locking mechanism to only allow `apps.populate` to happen in an idempotent, thread-safe manner.

The stripped down source for the `Apps` class which is what the singleton `apps` is instantiated from:

```
class Apps(object):

    def __init__(self, installed_apps=()):
        # Lock for thread-safe population.
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def populate(self, installed_apps=None):
        if self.ready:
            return

        with self._lock:
            if self.ready:
                return

            for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
                app_config.ready()

            self.ready = True
```

With this knowledge, you could create some `threading.Thread`'s that await on some condition.  These consumer threads will utilize `threading.Condition` to send cross-thread signals (which will enforce your ordering problem).  Here is a mocked out example of how that would work:

```
import threading

from django.apps import apps, AppConfig

# here we are using the "apps._lock" to synchronize our threads, which
# is the dirty little trick that makes this work
foo_ready = threading.Condition(apps._lock)

class FooAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "foo"

    def ready(self):
        t = threading.Thread(name='Foo.ready', target=self._ready_foo, args=(foo_ready,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def _ready_foo(self, foo_ready):
        with foo_ready:
            # setup foo
            foo_ready.notifyAll() # let everyone else waiting continue

class BarAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "bar"

    def ready(self):
        t = threading.Thread(name='Bar.ready', target=self._ready_bar, args=(foo_ready,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def _ready_bar(self, foo_ready):
        with foo_ready:
            foo_ready.wait() # wait until foo is ready
            # setup bar
```

Again, this ONLY allows you to control the flow of the `ready` calls from the individual `AppConfig`'s.  This doesn't control the order models get loaded, etc.

But if your first assertion was true, you have an `app.ready` implementation that depends on another app being ready first, this should do the trick.

Reasoning:

*Why Conditions?*  The reason this uses `threading.Condition` over `threading.Event` is two-fold.  Firstly, conditions are wrapped in a locking layer.  This means that you will continue to operate under controlled circumstances if the need arises (accessing shared resources, etc).  Secondly, because of this tight level of control, staying inside the `threading.Condition`'s context will allow you to chain the configurations in some desirable ordering.  You can see how that might be done with the following snippet:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
foo_ready = threading.Condition(lock)
bar_ready = threading.Condition(lock)
baz_ready = threading.Condition(lock)
```

*Why Deamonic Threads?*  The reason for this is, if your Django application were to die sometime between acquiring and releasing the lock in `apps.populate`, the background threads would continue to spin waiting for the lock to release.  Setting them to daemon-mode will allow the process to exit cleanly without needing to `.join` those threads.

Comment: (Ab)using the lock is quite clever! I wonder if it wouldn't be enough to spawn a thread in Bar that waits for app._lock to be released. Also, my understanding of the problem was that the app being waited for cannot be modified. If the apps can work together there is probably a simpler solution. Maybe @guettli can clarify.

Comment: @DanielHepper hahah "abuse" is definitely the right word!

If what you said is true, the app being "waited on" is not able to be modified, this would certainly not be the solution directly.  I think, as you said, just waiting for the lock might be sufficient for that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is very hackish. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.

Comment: They don't have to be modified.  Third-party AppConfigs can be overridden, though it may mean some duplicate code (or some hacky method copying: can you set a super call as the target of a thread?).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dummy app which only purpose is to fire a custom `all_apps_are_ready` signal (or method call on `AppConfig`).

Put this app at the end of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

If this app receives the `AppConfig.ready()` method call, you know that all other apps are ready.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

Subclass AppConfig and send a signal at the end of `ready`.  Use this subclass in all your apps.  If you have a dependency on one being loaded, hook up to that signal/sender pair.

If you need more details, don't hesitate!

There are some subtleties to this method:

1) Where to put the signal definition (I suspect in manage.py would work, or you could even monkey-patch `django.setup` to ensure it gets called everywhere that it is). You could put in a `core` app that is always the first one in installed_apps or somewhere where django will always load it before any `AppConfig`s are loaded.

2) Where to register the signal receiver (you should be able to do this in `AppConfig.__init__` or possibly just globally in that file).

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded

Therefore, the setup is as follow:

- When django first starts up, register the signal.
- at the end of every `app_config.ready` send the signal (with the `AppConfig` instance as the sender)
- in AppConfigs that need to respond to the signal, register a receiver in `__init__` with the appropriate sender.

Let me know how it goes!

If you need it to work for third-party apps, keep in mind that you can override the AppConfigs for these apps (convention is to place these in a directory called apps). Alternatively, you could monkey patch `AppConfig`

Comment: I updated the question and added an example. Do you think you question is still valid?

Comment: @guettli I've added some more details.  It's a bit more complicated then I initially thought, but I suspect it should work based on the Django docs.  The trick is getting everything in the right places ;)